# Find name in Arraylist, then transfer contents to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to find my name in an ArrayList of students, then transfer my selection of 50 choices to a new array called myChoices (will later be compared against others for matches). The Student class contains a name and an ArrayList of choices. Here is the relevant loop:

```
int matches[] = new int[students.size()];
int myChoices[] = new int[students.get(0).getChoices().size()];

for(int i = 0; i < students.get(i).getChoices().size(); i++){
    if(students.get(i).getName().equals("Garrett M")){
        myChoices[i] = students.get(i).getChoices().get(i);
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < myChoices.length; i++){
    System.out.println(myChoices[i]);
}
```

In the last loop, I'm just trying to print my choices, which come out as something like this:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0 
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

(That's not 50, but you get the gist of it -- in the output there's about 49 zeros and one 1.) The actual output should begin with 1 and be a mixture of 0,1, and -1:

1   -1  1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   -1  0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1

Any idea where I could be going wrong?

Comment: Are you aware that your code is overwriting the `myChoices` array for each student iteration?

Comment: I wasn't. I think I see where my mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same index `i` for both the `students` List and the `students.get(i).getChoices()` List. That's probably wrong.

You probably need a nested loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) { // iterate over the students to find the one
                                           // having the required name
    if(students.get(i).getName().equals("Garrett M")){
        // iterate over the choices of the found student and collect them into the array
        for (int j = 0; j < students.get(i).getChoices().size; j++) {
            myChoices[j] = students.get(i).getChoices().get(j);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. I completely overlooked the second for loop and changing my index. Thanks for breaking it down for me.

Answer (score 0):

By writing if statement inside loop you are only setting that particular element of mychoices[] array which matches with your name(Garrett M) rest all array element will remain as it is that is why you are getting 49 Zeros and 1 ones.

Answer (score 0):

At times, imperative programming may turn out to be confusing with a lot of `for` loops. *From ages, we have been using `for` far too many times in our code.* With Java 8, one can code in declarative style. A code written in declarative style is more easy to read and understand.

Just adding to what **@Eran** has answered, I'll try to simplify the same solution using Java 8 Stream APIs. Some day, this might come in handy for you, if not today.

The problem in hand is to get the choices of a particular student and add those choices in an array(or Collection).

This can be done as follows:

```
List<Integer> myChoicesList = students.stream()
                .filter(student -> student.getName().equals("Garrett M"))
                .map(student -> student.getChoices()) 
                .findFirst()
                .get();
```

- In the first step, convert your `students` list to a Java 8 `Stream`.
  Remember Stream is an abstraction:

  `students.stream()`
- Next, filter out that one particular student in which you are
  interested in:

  `filter(student -> student.getName().equals("Garrett M"))`
- At this point, the Stream contains that one student which was
  filtered. But we are interested in the `choices` that this student
  has. Hence, convert this stream of `Student` to a stream of
  `choices`:

  `.map(student -> student.getChoices())`
- Now that you have your choices, you can perform your desired
  operations on them. That's it!! Done!!

  `findFirst().get();`

This will give you a `List<Integer>`. Later you can convert this collection to an `Integer` array as:

`Integer[] myChoices = myChoicesList.toArray(new Integer[myChoicesList.size()]);`

**Note:** I've designed this snippet assuming that, `getChoices()` method from `Student` class returns a `List<Integer>` containing choices of that `Student`.